# Eloquent pivot : how to do select columns in Laravel 5.1

Tags: mysql, sql, eloquent, laravel-5.1, pivot-table

I have two models `Bill` & `Order`,
I can get `Orders` records via :

```
    $orders = $bill->orders;
```

But I want to use select like this :

```
 $orders = $bill->orders->select([
                            'orders.*',                            
                            \DB::raw('sum(orders.quantity) as qty'),
                            \DB::raw('sum(orders.price) as  total')                            
                            ]) 
                            ->groupBy('article_id');
```

I get this error :

```
Method select does not exist.
```

Please any one may help me, thanks !

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution :D

Just edit it like this :

```
 $orders = $bill->orders()->select([
                        'orders.*',                            
                        \DB::raw('sum(orders.quantity) as qty'),
                        \DB::raw('sum(orders.price) as  total')                            
                        ]) 
                        ->groupBy('article_id')->get();
```

and it's fine :)))